# How to add a table of contents in Latex using TeXStudio?

Tags: table-of-contents, texstudio

I'm trying to simply add a table of contents to my report using TeXStudio by using the following command after the abstract:

```
\tableofcontents
```

This creates a heading Table of Contents but it doesn't list the sections only the title of the report.

My headings are as follows: Intro,Lit Review,Methodology,Conclusion.

Does anyone have any idea how to remedy this?

This is the skeleton of the template with content removed:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% file typeinst.tex %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% This is the LaTeX source for the instructions to authors using
% the LaTeX document class 'llncs.cls' for contributions to
% the Lecture Notes in Computer Sciences series.
% http://www.springer.com/lncs       Springer Heidelberg 2006/05/04
%
% It may be used as a template for your own input - copy it
% to a new file with a new name and use it as the basis
% for your article.
%
% NB: the document class 'llncs' has its own and detailed documentation, see
% ftp://ftp.springer.de/data/pubftp/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/llncsdoc.pdf
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}


\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\urldef{\mailsa}\path|{firstname.lastname}@xxx.ie|

\begin{document}

\mainmatter  % start of an individual contribution

\title{Final Year Project Report}

\subtitle{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx }


\author{Brian Varley \inst{1}
}
%
\institute{xxxxxxx Institute of Technology, Ireland\\
\url{http://www.xxx.ie}\\
}

\maketitle


\begin{abstract}



\end{abstract}

\smallskip
\noindent \textbf{Keywords.} 



\tableofcontents




\section{Project Introduction}



\begin{itemize}
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
\end{itemize}


\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{myo}
  \caption{figure}{Thalmic Lab's Myo arm band}
  \label{fig:test1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{kinect}
  \caption{figure}{Microsoft Kinect V2 Sensor}
  \label{fig:test2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}


Kinect v2 sensor capabilities:

\begin{itemize}
  \item 
  \item 

\end{itemize}



The proposed application's core features are outlined as follows in order of precedence: 
\begin{itemize}
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
\end{itemize} 






\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{ Proposed physio application prototype system architecture, detailing flow of user input.}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{gesture_arc}
\end{figure}


\





\section{Literature Review}





\section{Methodology}
\label{sec:Applications of Vision Based Gesture Recognition in HCI} 




\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{ Proposed project time line.}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{initial_timieline}
\end{figure}



\section{Conclusion}




\section{Appendices}


\listoffigures



\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{Bibliography}



\end{document}
```

[image: table contents incorrect headings]

The declaration in the report:

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: To be more explicit, there's nothing in the code you posted that indicates what's going wrong. A simple test would be to replace whatever template you're likely using with `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} \tableofcontents \section{Project Introduction} ... \end{document}`. That will almost certainly work, indicating a problem in your template or preamble.

Comment: Note that you must compile *twice* to see the entries in the ToC. If you only compile once - or if you remove generated files between compilations - the ToC will be empty.

Comment: I compiled twice but the contents of the table is still just the title of my report. I'll re edit my question to include the above revisions.

Comment: @cfr using llncs class you could run latex 1000 times and still have truncated table of content. It's a feature:-0

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Good to know, I guess. Sounds like a feature MS or Apple would invent. (MS would invent it. Apple would retrospectively call it a feature when it emerged as a side-effect of something else.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `llncs` class has lots of interesting feature, unless publishing in LLNCS, it's probably not really the class I would choose.

Here it sets

```
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
```

so you might want to add

```
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
```

to your preamble so that your table of contents has some content.

Comment: I tried the above solution by adding the lie `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}` under the line that declares the table of contents. But the table stays the same, only show the report title as a heading.

Comment: @BrianJ The answer says to add it ***to your preamble***. Did you try that?

Comment: @BrianJ why add it there after the truncated table of contents has already been printed? Put it before `\begin{document}` as in the answer posted above.

Comment: Okay thanks for clarifying, I didn't know what the preamble was. Added it to the preamble now its working.